# Disable Chrome suggesting that I search on "How I Met Your Mother" wiki

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, google-search

If I type a question into Chrome search that begins with the word "How", it suggests that I search in the How I Met Your Mother wiki:

[image: Browser Screenshot]

It's been doing this for years. I have been to that wiki on purpose less than 5 times in the last two years, and none of those times in 2015.

Why does it do this? How do I turn it off?

I am using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.152 m

It's probably relevant that these times from many years ago do not even appear in the history anymore:

[image: History Screenshot]

Comment: You could try searching it in History and deleting the entries.

Comment: Also, under Privacy Settings, disable the second option (search predictions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn this off by going to "Google Chrome Search Engine Settings", using the url:

```
chrome://settings/searchEngines
```

If you scroll through the list of the "Other Search Engines", you should find the one for the "How I Met Your Mother Wiki." If you hover over it, you should see an "x" on the right side of the row. Click on that and Voila! It's gone!

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome automatically adds certain websites to Search if it is compatible with the feature, and you have visited the website a few times. The way Chrome does this is by identifying the search features on the websites you visit.

You are able to manage your personal Search by navigating to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`, and then removing the Search websites you don't want:

[image]

You can also make a website your default search engine, for instance if you're particularly addicted to Amazon, you can get your shopaholic fix right from the address bar!